# How to get the values in an appended table row using onchange event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function that gets the values from the database and then appends those data to a table. Now, there are instances that there will be 2 or more records from the database that are being retrieved, so 2 or more table rows are also appended.My problem is, how would I able to get the values of a specific row using onchange event since I have included a select option values in the table row being appended. I know its a bit confusing but can anybody help me with this? Thanks a lot. Here are my codes.

```
$.post("{{ url('create_po') }}", { 'prod_IDs': valArray }, function(data){
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    for(var i = 0; i < obj.prodval.length; i++){
        txt += "<tr class='info '><td><input type='number' class='form-control' style='width:100px;' value='0'/>"+
             "</td><td>"+obj.prodval[i].unit+
             "</td><td>"+obj.prodval[i].pharmaceutical+
             "</td><td>"+obj.prodval[i].packaging+
             "</td><td><input type='text' class='form-control' style='width:100px;' value='"+obj.prodval[i].price+"' disabled=disabled />"+
             "</td><td><input type='text' class='form-control' style='width:100px;' value='0' disabled=disabled />"+
             "</td></tr>";
    }
    $("#tbl-po-list").append(txt);
});
```

**My table**

```
<table id="tbl-po-list">
 <tbody id="po-create"></tbody>
</table>
```

Output:

[image]

**My revised table**

[image]

How can I get the values in a row using onchange event of the quantity represented as QTY in the image above? Please please help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use event delegation to bind events to dynamically added elements.

Comment: Something like this, `$('#tbl-po-list').on('change', '.info input', function(){})`.

Comment: Can you send me a link I can study on how to implement that?

Comment: But the rows above have the same class since it was appended through a loop when there are 2 or more records being retrieved.

Comment: I am sorry if I am going away from my real question, but how about if I change the value of total after onchange event? I will be so thankful if you will still answer this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have revised the table right now. The packaging column now requires an input but I only get blank value of it after putting the quantity value first. It only works unless the value of packaging is inputted first before setting the quantity value. How would I address this problem? Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use jQuery's Event delegation.

```
$( '#tbl-po-list' ).on( 'change' , 'input[type="number"]' ,function(){
    alert( 'Event fired' );
});
```

Did not mock the ajax request rather just appending a new row to the table on the click of a button in the below fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/ehcwhd7f/

Comment: Yes, this is working, but how would I able to get the values in the row where onchange event happens?

Comment: If you want the value of the quantity field then please use `$( this ).val()` to get the value entered in the inputbox.

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ehcwhd7f/1/

Comment: How about the remaining fields?

Comment: How about this updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ehcwhd7f/2/
1. Use `$( this ).parents( '.info' )` to get the row element.
2. Find for the field value that you want to fetch from the row element : `$( this ).parents( '.info').find( '.price' )` . In place of `.price` provide your required selector.

Comment: You can add. However, make sure you are providing the proper selector to fetch the values. I provided the `.price` and `.total` class to the fields in the fiddle to make things simpler.

Comment: I am sorry if I am going away from my real question, but how about if I change the value of total after onchange event? I will be so thankful if you will still answer this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is simple :

In the `onchange` event handler get the value in the qty field and the price field. Multiply them and set the result in the total field.

Here is the updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ehcwhd7f/3/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106138/discussion-between-user3613129-and-eli).

Answer (score 0):

Amateur Answer Alert:

```
table.rows[0].cells[0].children[0].value
```